# Javascript looping error with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to prompt the user for a weight smaller than 126. Then my javascript is supposed to classify the weight into a category. I have used arrays but every time I loop it writes the 3rd array, superfly class. What can I do to make it function properly?

```
var wArray = ["fly", "superfly", "bantam", "superbantam", "feather"];
var weight = parseInt(prompt("What is your weight?"), 10);

while (weight > 126) {
    alert('Please enter a weight lighter than 126');
    weight = parseInt(prompt("What is your weight?"), 10);
}

recruit();

function recruit() {
    var weightClass = wArray[0];

    if (0 < weight && weight < 112) {
        weightClass = wArray[1];
    } else if (112 < weight && weight < 115) {
        weightClass = wArray[2];
    } else if (weight > 115 && weight < 118) {
        weightClass = wArray[3];
    } else if (weight > 118 && weight < 122) {
        weightClass = wArray[4];
    } else if (weight > 122 && weight < 126) {
        weightClass = wArray[5];
    }

    document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML = ('You are in ' + weightClass + ' class!');
}
```

Comment: You've got some gaps in your weight. Your if() structure makes it impossible for someone to be exactly 115 or 18 or 122 pounds.

Comment: should i use a float? to change to decimal?

Comment: No, it should be something like `} else if (weight >= 115 && weight < 118) {` so that 115 is (and the other numbers) are included as possible weights. (note the `=` sign in there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first if condition is incorrect.  You say `if (112 < weight < 115)`.  This first does `112 < weight`, then takes the result of that and compares it to `115`.

`112 < weight` evaluates to `true` or `false`; when used in numeric comparisons, `true` is 1 and `false` is 0.  (Obviously) both 1 and 0 will always be less than 115, so this condition will always be true.

---

Also note that this script should be run `onload` of the page.  This is because the div with the ID `weight` may not have loaded when the script executes and attempts to populate it.  You can do this by saying:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var wArray = ["fly", "superfly", "bantam", "superbantam", "feather"];

    function calculateWeight() {
        var weight = parseInt(prompt("What is your weight?"), 10);

        while (weight > 126) {
            alert('Please enter a weight lighter than 126');
            weight = parseInt(prompt("What is your weight?"), 10);
        }

        recruit();
    }

    function recruit() {
        var weightClass = wArray[0];

        if (weight >= 112 && weight < 115) {
            weightClass = wArray[1];
        } else if (weight >= 115 && weight < 118) {
            weightClass = wArray[2];
        } else if (weight >= 118 && weight < 122) {
            weightClass = wArray[3];
        } else if (weight >= 122 && weight < 126) {
            weightClass = wArray[4];
        }

        document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML = ('You are in ' + weightClass + ' class!');

    }
</script>
<body onload="calculateWeight()">
    <!-- include body contents here -->
</body>
```

Comment: Also note the `>=` comparison operators in the code above. Your original code effectively created one-pound gaps at the top of each weight class which would return `wArray[0]` for `weightClass` if entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

the line:

if (112 < weight < 115) {

Should be

if (112 < weight && weight < 115) {

Comment: To elaborate: No matter what number you use for `weight`, the expression `112 < weight < 115` will always be true.

Comment: yeah, there is still an error, it will not alert me of the final weight class

Comment: Do you get "fly" when you put in 126? You'll want to use <= instead of just <. But if one conditional is weight <= 122, the other should be weight > 122. Like what Marc B said above, you'll want to capture those instances where someone puts in the exact values. Which is what's happening with 126. (it gets past the while because weight (126) **is not** greater than 126. It's equal to.

Comment: at the moment, i dont get anything from it at all, but it used to keep putting me in superfly class with any number valid under 126